# How to default the [Yn] responses for the Ruby "gem clean" command?

Tags: ruby, automation, rubygems, default, prompt

I regularly use the Ruby `gem clean` command to keep the local gem repository in shape.

However, due to dependency issues, many a times the command returns a prompt such as:

```
XXXXX-1.0.6 depends on [YYYYYY (~> 0.8.4)]
If you remove this gems, one or more dependencies will not be met.
Continue with Uninstall? [Yn]
```

While this is simple enough, it requires manual intervention (for the `[Yn]` response), and hence this is preventing me from creating a simple `cron` script to automate this process.

Any ideas on how to default the response for these `gem` prompts?

Answer (score 10):

You should have a `yes` command, the OSX version has this to say:

```
YES(1)                    BSD General Commands Manual                   YES(1)

NAME
     yes -- be repetitively affirmative

SYNOPSIS
     yes [expletive]

DESCRIPTION
     yes outputs expletive, or, by default, ``y'', forever.

HISTORY
     The yes command appeared in 4.0BSD.

4th Berkeley Distribution        June 6, 1993        4th Berkeley Distribution
```

So perhaps this will work:

```
yes n | gem clean
```

`gem clean` might be reading directly from the terminal rather than the standard input. In that case, you might have `expect` kicking around:

> **Expect** is a  program that "talks" to other interactive programs according to a script.  Following the script, **Expect** knows what can be expected from a program and what the correct response should be.  An interpreted language provides branching and high-level control structures  to  direct the dialogue.  In addition, the user can take control and interact directly when desired, afterward returning control to the script.

So you could write an `expect` script to respond to the expected prompts with "y" or "n" as desired.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
echo|gem clean
```

It'll act like hitting return at the prompt. 'y' being the default, it'll run `gem clean` to completion.

Comment: I just tested this and it doesn't seem to behave as expected. In my environment I feed gem clean an "n" in these situations. So, I ran... "echo 'n' | gem clean" and it treated it as a y and cleaned out the gems anyway.

Comment: You're right - however, it still does the trick I guess. Edited to be less misleading.

Answer (score 0):

Thilo's answer is the simplest. However if you need to use "n" you're out of luck. Some searching found this thread with some sample Java code: [Java: Detecting user prompt when running a batch script from Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4450326/java-detecting-user-prompt-when-running-a-batch-script-from-java)

I modified it some for this situation, and I think this will allow you the more conservative option of using "n" as the default choice. Of course, this code can be modified into a bash script if you prefer not to have a java class running in your cron jobs - but I'll leave that to someone more experienced with bash.

I don't have an easy way to test this code right now, so let me know how it fares. :)

```
public static void main(final String... args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    final Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
    final String command = "..."; // cmd.exe
    final String matchString = "Continue with Uninstall? [Yn] ";
    final String response = "n";

    final Process proc = runtime.exec(command, null, new File("."));

    final BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(proc.getInputStream()));
    final BufferedWriter output = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(proc.getOutputStream()));

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    char[] cbuf = new char[100];
    while (input.read(cbuf) != -1) {
        sb.append(cbuf);
        if (sb.substring(sb.length() - matchString.length(), sb.length()).equals(matchString)) {
            output.write(response);
            output.newLine();
            output.flush();
        }
    }
    System.out.println(sb);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Recent versions of `gem` have flags for this. For example, to ignore dependencies use `-I`. To automatically remove executables, use `-x`. Most options are equivalent to answering `yes` to a specific class of prompt. Prepend a `no-` to the extended option name to answer no instead of yes.

```
Options:
    -a, --[no-]all                   Uninstall all matching versions
    -I, --[no-]ignore-dependencies   Ignore dependency requirements while
                                     uninstalling
    -D, --[no-]check-development     Check development dependencies while uninstalling
                                     (default: false)
    -x, --[no-]executables           Uninstall applicable executables without
                                     confirmation
    -i, --install-dir DIR            Directory to uninstall gem from
    -n, --bindir DIR                 Directory to remove binaries from
        --[no-]user-install          Uninstall from user's home directory
                                     in addition to GEM_HOME.
        --[no-]format-executable     Assume executable names match Ruby's prefix and suffix.
        --[no-]force                 Uninstall all versions of the named gems
                                     ignoring dependencies
        --[no-]abort-on-dependent    Prevent uninstalling gems that are
                                     depended on by other gems.
    -v, --version VERSION            Specify version of gem to uninstall
        --platform PLATFORM          Specify the platform of gem to uninstall
        --vendor                     Uninstall gem from the vendor directory.
                                     Only for use by gem repackagers.
```

As an example, to wipe all your gems out, you could use `gem uninstall -Iax`