# Detecting user prompt when running an exe file from Java

Tags: java, command, processbuilder, runtime.exec

I am trying to execute an exe file from my java code....Upon execution,this file prompts the user for password and then password verification..

So basically, the problem i am having is being able to assign the password and its verification.Have tried the solutions on previous posts on this topic especially this one:[Java: Detecting user prompt when running a batch script from Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4450326/java-detecting-user-prompt-when-running-a-batch-script-from-java), which uses output stream to write to the command line but this doesn't work for me as code hangs if a read operation is performed. Here is what i have done:

[image of my command line when run manually outside java](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o2Uay.png)

```
basically the link above is an image of my commandline, which looks like this:

    C:/Program Files//com/ExecCodes/bin64>install.exe <hit enter>
    C:/Program Files//com/ExecCodes/bin64>Password:    <hit enter>
    C:/Program Files//com/ExecCodes/bin64>Verify:       <hit enter>
```

`string command ="C:/Program Files//com/ExecCodes/bin64/install.exe";`

```
final Process p = runtime.exec(command);

             final BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                        p.getInputStream()));

             StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                char[] cbuf = new char[100];
//My code hangs here..>> while (input.read(cbuf) != -1) {
                    sb.append(cbuf);
                    if (sb.toString().contains("Password:")) {
                        break;
                    }
                    else (sb.toString().contains("Verify:")) {
                        break;
                    }
                }
```

How do i fix this code to enable me enter a password..???

Comment: Just a wild guess, but you may have to use [`ProcessBuilder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html) and redirect the input.

Comment: I tried proces Builder but it doesn't still accept passwords

Comment: *"image of my command line when run manually outside java"*  Not following a link to something that should be represented **here** as **text.**

Comment: See also [When Runtime.exec() won't](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2071275/core-java/when-runtime-exec---won-t.html) for many good tips on creating and handling a process correctly.  Then ignore it refers to `exec` and use a `ProcessBuilder` to create the process.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. I have been to this site and i am certain the syntax isn't a problem. I tried executing another exe file which didn't require a password and everything went on fine. The problem am having is getting my password to the exec command or even process builder. My code hangs at one spot waiting for authentication.